# Scheduling java method wit persistance

Tags: quartz-scheduler, scheduling, scheduler, boot, cron4j

I need to execute a call to a particular method daily or more, considering that the app may and the machine may reboot. 
I saw examples where they just put the thread to sleep but I need persistance, managing system rebooting.

I have to be sure that if I switch off my machine when I reboot it reprises task execution.

I found schedulers as cron4j and quartz but don't get if it's possible, and if it is, how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

With Quartz you will only need to configure it with a persistent job store implementation and that is pretty much all there is to it. I suggest that you read through the [Quartz scheduler tutorial](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/tutorials/), especially the chapter that describes [Quartz job stores](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-09).